# FluentAssertions won't exclude missing members on object graph comparison

Tags: c#, .net, fluentvalidation, fluent-assertions

I'm trying to compare a DTO with its respective entity using FluentAssertions [object graph comparison](https://fluentassertions.com/objectgraphs/). My entity has some extra metadata properties that my DTO does not have.

I'm trying to exclude these extra properties with the `ExcludingMissingMembers` options and even explicitly by excluding each member by itself like so:

```cs
result.Entity.Should().BeEquivalentTo(dto, opt => opt
  .ExcludingMissingMembers()
  .Excluding(x => x.ValidationResult)
  .Excluding(x => x.CreatedBy)
  .Excluding(x => x.CreatedAt));
```

But my test keeps failing because of the extra properties my DTO does not have.

> Message: Expected result.Entity (of type Entity) to be
>
> Entity
> {
> CreatedAt = <0001-01-01 00:00:00.000>
> CreatedBy = 
> FinancialResourcesOrigins = {Labor, Labor}
> ProductsOfInterest = {FixedIncome, FixedIncome}
> ValidationResult =
> }, but found
>
> Dto
> {
> FinancialResourcesOrigins = {Labor, Labor}
> ProductsOfInterest = {FixedIncome, FixedIncome}
> }
>
> With configuration:
>
> - Use declared types and members
> - Compare enums by value
> - Exclude member ValidationResult
> - Exclude member CreatedBy
> - Exclude member CreatedAt
> - Match member by name (or throw)
> - Be strict about the order of items in byte arrays
> - Without automatic conversion.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

So, a fast test result:

```
var entity = new
    {
        CreatedAt = DateTime.Now,
        CreatedBy = "",
        FinancialResourcesOrigins = new[] { "Labor", "Labor" },
        ProductsOfInterest = new[] { "FixedIncome", "FixedIncome" },
        ValidationResult = ""
    };

var dto = new
    {
        FinancialResourcesOrigins = new[] { "Labor", "Labor" },
        ProductsOfInterest = new[] { "FixedIncome", "FixedIncome" },
    };


entity.Should()
     .BeEquivalentTo(dto, opt => opt
     .ExcludingMissingMembers());
```

This should work as expected.

Your mistake seems to be the explicit exclude, as the members (your variables x) are expected from your DTO, where they are not present

Comment: I only added the explicit excludes after testing only with `ExcludingMissingMenbers()` and it returning the same exact error. So your answer does not solve my issue. Even using only the explicit excludes results in the same error.

Comment: Can you please add your full object representations?

Answer (score 0):

From source code of [ExcludingMissingMembers()](https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions/blob/17c52d0e2d6adb366fbf8b57eabe69d7c3d2b131/Src/FluentAssertions/Equivalency/SelfReferenceEquivalencyAssertionOptions.cs#L391):

> Tries to match the members of the subject with equally named members
> on the expectation. Ignores those members that **don't exist on the
> expectation** and previously registered matching rules.

In your scenario "expectation" is a `dto` object, because `entity`(subject) have all properties from `dto` object, there are nothing to ignore.

You can achieve desired result by switching places of `dto` and `entity`

```
dto.Should().BeEquivalentTo(result.Entity, opt => opt.ExcludingMissingMembers());
```

After switching their places `entity` become an "expectation" and it's properties which is missing on the `dto`(subject) will be ignored

However this approach makes failing message a bit confusing, for example when `result.Entity` is `null`, message would be: *Expected entity to be , but found Dto { .. }*

Answer (score 0):

FluentAssertions 6.8.0

```
actualValue.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectedValue, options
            => options.Using(new IgnoreNullMembersInExpectation()));

public class IgnoreNullMembersInExpectation : IEquivalencyStep
{
    public EquivalencyResult Handle(Comparands comparands, IEquivalencyValidationContext context, IEquivalencyValidator nestedValidator)
    {
        if(comparands.Expectation is null)
        {
            return EquivalencyResult.AssertionCompleted;
        }

        return EquivalencyResult.ContinueWithNext;
    }
}
```